# Installing Sbt on Ubuntu

Tags: scala, ubuntu, unix, sbt

I am trying to install SBT on ubuntu for the 1st time, have referred below link for the installation, but getting errors, please help me to fix it.

I need [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html) for the Spark and scala projects.

**sudo apt-get update**

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Have you added sbt bintary repo to `apt` source list ?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps ?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually download and install the `sbt` package like in the following:

```
curl -OL https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v1.0.3/sbt-1.0.3.tgz
tar xzf sbt-1.0.3.tgz

sudo mv sbt /usr/local/
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/sbt sbt /usr/local/sbt/sbt-1.0.3/bin/sbt 100
```